# Angular Module Loading Issue with AngularJS-ResponsiveCalendar

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use the AngularJS-ResponsiveCalendar on my page. Here is the link to the actual control:

https://github.com/twinssbc/AngularJS-ResponsiveCalendar

I have an Index file which contains the following:

```
<!-- Adding the Angular Javascript Files -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://twinssbc.github.io/AngularJS-ResponsiveCalendar/dist/js/calendar-tpls.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/scheduleController.js"></script>
```

In the scheduleController.js I have the following:

```
angular.module('App', ['ui-rCalendar'])
```

I think the above line causes the issue:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=GCCICR&p1=Error%3A%…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.5%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A381)
```

Comment: 'ui.rCalendar' is the right name you should use I suppose when injecting the module.

Comment: Apart from that, how do you initialise ng-app in your code?